# certbot doesn't run from crontab

Tags: command-line, 18.04, bash, cron

I installed certbot from pip3:

```
# pip3 freeze|grep -i certbot
certbot==1.5.0
certbot-apache==1.5.0
certbot-dns-digitalocean==1.5.0
```

I can run certbot from the command line as root, but I configured crontab to run `perl -e 'sleep int(rand(1800))' && certbot -q renew` as root twice a week, and I get this error message by email:

```
/bin/sh: 1: certbot: not found
```

If I type `whereis certbot` at the command line I get this result:

```
certbot: /usr/local/bin/certbot
```

Why doesn't certbot run from crontab successfully?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use fill paths within `crontab` while your executable doesn't belong to the cron's PATH, which by default includes only `/bin` and `/usr/bin`. So your cronjob should look like:

```
* * * * * perl -e 'sleep int(rand(1800))' && /usr/local/bin/certbot -q renew
```

You could customize the cron's environment as it is shown at the last point [here](https://linuxize.com/post/scheduling-cron-jobs-with-crontab/#:%7E:text=Crontab%20Variables,-The%20cron%20daemon&text=The%20default%20path%20is%20set,do%20with%20a%20regular%20script.), but IMO it is better to change your scripts (and cronjobs) to work with the default environment, thus they will be more portable, when you are setup a new system, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**TL:DR** For Ubuntu 20.04 users, don't forget that certbot is installed with snapd.

This answer and question put me on the right path. In Ubuntu 20.04, certbot perfers snapd. I had installed by following a tutorial but had forgotten about all about snap. @Uri's `whereat certbot` helped to remind me that the location had changed. Either run

> 0 2 * * 1 /snap/bin/certbot renew

or include snap in the PATH environment variable

> SHELL=/bin/sh
> PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:**/snap/bin**

https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntufocal-apache

*** Highlight emphasis mine
[image]